How to animate cycloidal disk and its dynamic motion inside the drive?
I am working on animating the movement of a cycloidal disk inside a cycloidal drive using parametric equations in Mathematica. The cycloidal drive has various components like rollers, output holes, and the rotor, which are represented in the following code.
(*Equation for a Cycloidal Disk*)
    R = 60; d = 10; e = 3; n = 10; r = 12; ro = 36; nh = 6;
    \[Psi] = -ArcTan[Sin[(1 - n)*t]/((R/(e*n)) - Cos[(1 - n)*t])];
    X[t_] := R*Cos[t] - d*Cos[t - \[Psi]] - e*Cos[n*t];
    Y[t_] := -R*Sin[t] + d*Sin[t - \[Psi]] + e*Sin[n*t];
    
    rotor = ParametricPlot[{X[t] + e, Y[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
       PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
       PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
       Axes -> True];(*Cycloidal Disk*)
    rollers = 
      Table[Graphics[{Orange, EdgeForm[Blue], 
         Disk[{R*Cos[2*Pi/n*k], R*Sin[2*Pi/n*k]}, d]}], {k, 1, 
        n}]; (*Orange circles*)
    outputHoles = 
      Table[Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Blue], 
         Disk[{ro*Cos[2*Pi/nh*k] + e, ro*Sin[2*Pi/nh*k]}, 6]}], {k, 1, 
        nh}]; (* 6 Blue circles*)
    centerCircle = 
      ParametricPlot[{r*Cos[t] + e, r*Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]; (*Blue center circle*)
    outputP = 
      Table[Graphics[{Brown, EdgeForm[Black], 
         Disk[{ro*Cos[2*Pi/nh*k], ro*Sin[2*Pi/nh*k]}, 6 - e]}], {k, 1, 
        nh}]; (*Brown outer circle*)
    
    justAvisualContour = 
      ParametricPlot[{R*Cos[t], R*Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All,
        AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
       PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}];
    
    Show[rotor, rollers, outputHoles, centerCircle, outputP, \
    justAvisualContour, Axes -> True]


I can visualize all the static components of the drive (rotor, rollers, output holes, etc.), but I would like to animate the cycloidal disk (rotor) to show its dynamic motion inside the drive. Specifically, I want to show how the cycloidal disk moves while maintaining its interaction with the rollers and the output holes.

R = 60; d = 10; e = 3; n = 10; r = 12; ro = 36; nh = 6;
\[Psi] = -ArcTan[Sin[(1 - n)*t]/((R/(e*n)) - Cos[(1 - n)*t])];
X[t_] := R*Cos[t] - d*Cos[t - \[Psi]] - e*Cos[n*t];
Y[t_] := -R*Sin[t] + d*Sin[t - \[Psi]] + e*Sin[n*t];

rotor[fi_] := 
  ParametricPlot[
   RotationMatrix[fi/9] . {X[t], Y[t]} + 
    RotationMatrix[-fi] . {e, 0}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, Axes -> True];
(*Cycloidal Disk*)

rollers = 
  Table[Graphics[{Orange, EdgeForm[Blue], 
     Disk[{R*Cos[2*Pi/n*k], R*Sin[2*Pi/n*k]}, d]}], {k, 1, n}];
(*Orange circles*)

outputHoles[fi_] := 
  Table[Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Blue], 
     Disk[RotationMatrix[
         fi/9] . ({ro*Cos[2*Pi/nh*k], ro*Sin[2*Pi/nh*k]}) + 
       RotationMatrix[-fi] . {e, 0}, 6]}], {k, 1, nh}];
(*6 Blue circles*)

centerCircle[fi_] := 
  ParametricPlot[
   RotationMatrix[-fi] . {r*Cos[t] + e, r*Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
(*Blue center circle*)

outputP[fi_] := 
  Table[Graphics[{Brown, EdgeForm[Black], 
     Disk[RotationMatrix[fi/9] . {ro*Cos[2*Pi/nh*k], 
        ro*Sin[2*Pi/nh*k]}, 6 - e]}], {k, 1, nh}];
(*Brown outer circle*)

justAvisualContour = 
  ParametricPlot[{R*Cos[t], R*Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All,
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}];

Manipulate[
 Show[rotor[fi], rollers, outputHoles[fi], centerCircle[fi], 
  outputP[fi], justAvisualContour, Axes -> True], {fi, 0, 9*2 Pi}]



